# How can perl cgi scripts can be executed in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, perl, cgi

I am using **Apache 2** server.
Can anyone please tell me where to put cgi files in **ubuntu**
Please explain the steps to execute the cgi scripts through the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory '/var/www/http/cgi-bin' 
Place your script 'program_name.cgi' there 
 in browser: http://localhost/cgi-bin/program_name.cgi
If it is not working, you should enable executing cgi scripts in apache config file

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on Ubuntu14:

```
sudo bash
cat <<'E' > /etc/apache2/conf-available/mycgis.conf
ScriptAlias /helloworld "/var/www/cgi/helloworld.pl"
E
a2enconf mycgis            #enables the new mycgis.conf file
a2enmod cgi                #enables the cgi module (unless already enabled)
service apache2 restart    #after conf change restart is needed
mkdir /var/www/cgi
cat <<'E' > /var/www/cgi/helloworld.pl     #a simple cgi script
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\nHello world!\n";
E
chmod +x /var/www/cgi/helloworld.pl        #make it executable
curl 127.0.0.1/helloworld                  #test it (or use a browser)
```

Comment: Can you explain what these commands are going? Also, OP asked WHERE the CGI scripts were installed, and while this script appears to set things you, without explanation you may leave OP no more learned than before. Please, just a small amount of explanation will make your answers much, much better.

Comment: You can put cgi scripts wherever you want as long as you tell apache about it. The man command more often than not explains plenty.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Man can be helpful (RFTM and all that) but is often also overwhelming and will contain information extraneous to the desired function. Adding explanatory information to your post makes it easy on the OP and makes your answer more helpful.